# Selenium Java Lib Not Import In Gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium, gradle

Selenium Java Lib Not Import In Gradle
import org.openqa is not Exist In spring boot project
This Code My Gradle Import words
my code is problem?

(Spring boot Version : 2.4.2)

`compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'`

[image: My Gradle Codes]

Comment: We are going to need more details from you to be able to answer your question. 
Could you edit your question to include your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Added My gradle Code Picture

Comment: When you run gradle build, what is the error you get?

Comment: Do not take an image capture of your code or any text file if you can avoid it. You should instead copy/paste it into a code block.

Comment: Jerin D Joy - not problem or error build in gradle